# Projector and Ray with OrthographicCamera

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

Is it possible to use Projector and Ray with OrthographicCamera?
I searched for it but I didn't find any example or documents.
Also my Camera isn't set in center of screen.
 
`camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0, width, 0, height, orthonear, orthofar);`
That mean top left will be (0 ,0). 
So  I don't think below code works correctly.
`mouse.x = ( event.clientX / width ) * 2 - 1;`
`mouse.y = -( event.clientY / height) * 2 + 1;`
So how can I use Projector and Ray with OrthographicCamera or any other methods to interact with objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original example:

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_voxelpainter.html

Use the DAT.GUI controls on the right to change the camera to Orthographic...

A little snippet from the code:

```
ray = projector.pickingRay( mouse2D.clone(), camera ); 
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```